# How to get latest only from certain folders in TFS using tfpt uu?

Tags: tfs-power-tools

My workspace is set to map to the root of the TFS server, which has many projects. When I do a tfpt uu, it gets the entire server. I don't want to cloak every folder that I don't currently need. Is there as easy way to do something like

tfpt uu root/theFolderINeed

Comment: tfpt uu should only get files that you have pending changes on to compare I believe.

Comment: Nope, it gets the entire workspace (which is the root of the TFS server in my case)

Comment: @DylanSmith is correct, it *undoes unchanged checkouts*.  If you don't have anything checked out, there's nothing to do.  Are you regularly checking out the root?  Are you using a local workspace or a server workspace?

Answer (score 0):

tfpt uu will undo any pending changes (check-outs) on files that are identical to the server version of that file (undu unchanged).

The only files that command should be "getting" are files which you have pending change on, so it can do a compare to determine if they are unchanged.

If you are trying to get (aka download) a specific folder, then tfpt uu is not the correct command.

Comment: It doesn't even do a get of the file contents, it just does a query to get the MD5 hash and compares those.